# Is there a way to make elements be relative to a position:fixed element?

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar at the top of the page that I want to be fixed. The problem is that if I make it fixed as opposed to absolute or something, stuff that would normally be below it takes its place and it sits on top making the content invisible. Any way I can get them to notice the fixed element and position accordingly without having to position:absolute or position:relative all of them?

Comment: If you know the size of the navbar you can add corresponding padding or margin to `body` to push everything down.

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav{
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply a `margin-top` or `padding-top` to the first non-fixed element on the page, with a value as high as the height of the fixed-position navbar. Typically that element would be `main`, the first `section` or similar, possibly also simply the first (non-fixed) `div`, depending on your page structure.